# TFS Merging Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, merge

We have a 0, 1, 2, 3 branch.

0 is for developers to check in partially completed/completed work.

1 is for QA.

We had some consultants break process and code directly into 1.

We've since checked in and merged code from 0 to 1.

Now we have two branches that don't match, as well as now not being able to merge changes into 1 due to a unit test that is failing because of those changes that were made.

Is the best solution to manually merge everything down from 1 to 0?

Would that blow away the changes that are currently in 0 that haven't made it to 1?

Comment: There have been several check-ins/merges since the rogue 1 check-in. Rolling back that changeset would potentially cause the build to fail as code that was merged may be dependent. Also, the consultants are no longer with us, so having them sort out their own code isn't an option unfortunately. What I ended up doing was simply merging 1 to 0, manually merging the conflicts. Still not where I'd like it to be, but it's closer.

Answer (score 2):

You could roll-back the change made to branch 1?

[TFS POwer tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) will let you do that I think by giving you an additional context option on the source control explorer.

Either that or "manually" roll-back by re-applying from the last successful merge (let the person that broke process sort it out! :) )

Comment: +1. Don't dig a deeper hole, roll back the incorrect change. You can achieve a rollback without installing anything else by using the [tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776(v=vs.100).aspx) command-line tool - just open a Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: Agreed on the console front, it is certainly do-able without installing anything else, though from an ease point of view the power-tools do simplify the process a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to manually merge anything here. You can go ahead and merge the changes from branch 1 to 0, it wouldnt blow any changes off from 0. All the files which were modified in both the branches should show up as a conflict during the merge which you will have to manually work through.